# jQuery adding newly created string into .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a jQuery function to make my font size responsive to width changes. I know there are other alternatives like Media Query but I want the size changes to be smooth. Using `vw` or `vh` is not what I am looking for.

So far I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).on('resize',callbackwidth);

   function callbackwidth(width) {

       var para_size = $('window').width()/100;

       var str = para_size.toString();

       var str = str + 'pt';

       $('.container p').css('font-size', $ );

   }
})
```

But this doesn't work. Any help with this or other similar ways of doing this? I would like to stick with jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: `$('window')` should be `$(window)`. Another thing `$('.container p').css('font-size', str);`

Comment: Have you tested whether the callback is called at all? If yes, have you tested whether str contains the right string? "this doesn't work" isn't clear enough to me.

Comment: Yes @Tushar it works!

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake on my part. Changed `$('window')` to `$(window)`

Comment: Did this solved the issue? Please recheck my comment